# Logic App connector for Azure Data Factory not showing existing factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I am not sure if I found a bug, or I am doing something wrong.

I created Data Factory "A" (ADF A) with a pipeline (TesterPipe). I published changes into Azure DevOps in "master branch". I then created second Data Factory "B" (ADF B), connected it to same Azure DevOps and used "master branch" to populate it with contents from ADF A.

Problem is, when I want to execute pipeline from Logic Apps, "**TesterPipe**" is fully visible in Logic App action when **ADF A** is selected. However, when I try to run same pipeline in **ADF B** via Logic App, I am not able to select it in the dropdown of available pipelines and when I write its name manually in, and run the logic app, I get an error "*Entity TesterPipe" not found*".

Notes:

- ADFs are in different resource groups
- when I remove git repo from ADF B, create a new pipeline, save and publish ADF B without git repo, I can run it from the same Logic App

Do you have an idea why is this happening? I can execute this pipeline in both ADFs manually, everything works as expected, except this.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you do not commit and deploy your code. I had to do it and then it started to show up